# Java Debug Adapter Protocol

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, debugging, remote-debugging, language-server-protocol

I want to have Debug Adapter Protocol for Java for my application, I did much research but found only `vscode` implementations that can't be used for my app (because it contains a local `vscode` package).

I know that Debug Adapter Protocol for Java can be activated by giving some requests to the language server, which will return `port` as a response on which it will be available. I started to dive deep into codes from `vscode` and `vscode-java-debug`, but can't figure out which I need. I only found that `vscode` has the following wrapped command using which it activated java DAP.

```
export const JAVA_START_DEBUGSESSION = "vscode.java.startDebugSession";
```

Maybe someone knows, what kind of request is it or can give some examples?

I activated the java language server using the following command below:

```
java \
    -Declipse.application=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.id1 \
    -Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4 \
    -Declipse.product=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.product \
    -Dlog.level=ALL \
    -noverify \
    -Xmx1G \
    --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM \
    --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED \
    -jar ./plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.200.v20180922-1751.jar \
    -configuration ./config_linux \
    -data /path/to/data
```

You can find more details from here: https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls/blob/master/README.md#running-from-the-command-line

Comment: Have you checked out https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-mock-debug? That should teach you quite a lot about DAP and its implementation. The Java debugging extension is a much more complicated sample that mixes DAP and LSP so as to provide better user experience, but your own debugger adapter can live without LSP.

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **convert** your images of text into actual text? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Comment: Thanks for the response @LexLi, I don't want to implement my own DAP, I want to use already written ones. I solved the problem of starting Debug Adapter for `js` and `python3` by finding their executables using `vscode` extension.

Starting to investigate java, I understood that java is a little bit different there is no executable, you should have a port and connect to that port. So, I wanted to know is there an easy solution for java?

Comment: I see. So, what you really want is the actual debugger/debug server. Then the Java one Microsoft created is in https://github.com/microsoft/java-debug Sadly there isn't enough documentation around such components, so all you can do is digest the code.